# "localhost redirected you too many times" opening custom Spring Security login page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

"localhost redirected you too many times" opening custom Spring Security login page

java 19, spring webmvc 6.0.13, spring security 6.0.8

security config page:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class ServicePlatformSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    UserDetailsManager users(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcUserDetailsManager users = new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);
        return users;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) throws Exception {
        MvcRequestMatcher.Builder builder = new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeRequests) -> authorizeRequests
                .requestMatchers(builder.pattern("/WEB-INF/view/**")).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(builder.pattern("/login")).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(builder.pattern("/**")).hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll());
        
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

controller for login:

```
@Controller
class LoginController {
    @GetMapping("/login")
    
    String login() {
        System.out.println("debug");
        return "login";
    }
}
```

[file structure for jsp views:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vbks.png)

Eventually I want to restrict authentication to certain endpoints. But for right now, I'm simply trying to get redirected to my custom login page when going to any url in my app. Instead I get a browser error "localhost redirected you too many times." It works with default login.

Comment: ok, this is because I didnt have logs enabled. I enabled the logs and realized it was an issue with my login.jsp, I was using spring form tags which expect a modelAttribute to bind the POST form data to but this must not be the type of setup that spring is expecting, after taking out the Spring form tags, it works.

Comment: ok, this is because I didnt have logs enabled. I enabled the logs and realized it was an issue with my login.jsp, I was using spring form tags which expect a modelAttribute to bind the POST form data, causing an error because none was configured.  this must not be the type of setup that spring is expecting, after taking out the Spring form tags, it works. Issue: rendering of jsp failing causing redirect to error page which is authenticated currently causing a redirect to the login url which... throws an error hence the loop